# PostgreSQL Full Outer Join Using Position

Tags: postgresql

Why is it that in PostgreSQL you cannot use:

FULL OUTER JOIN
 . . .
ON POSITION(table1.column1 IN table2.column1) <> 0,

But you can accomplish the same thing with a left join and a right join and then using a union all to join the results. It's the same exact result set that I want and I feel it should be possible since it's possible to just do the right and left join manually. I can live with having to do it, but it'd be a lot simpler to write with just using a Full Outer Join.

Comment: If the operation were to work like a left or right join then ON POSITION would join the two results if it found the substring of table1.column1 in table2.column1

It should also be stated that the values types are both varchars or strings

Comment: Ah - I thought it was something from Oracle or some such. You're just trying to match "word" to "phrase" or some such. I'm fairly certain it's just a planner limitation at present. I can't see anything on the todo list (http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo) though it seems that there's a mention here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7608.1006116788@sss.pgh.pa.us